# Highchart tooltip issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

In my current project we are using Hightchart to show charts  for various analysis.
In **line chart** we are showing tooltip on hover.
when there are only two series(two lines) charts renders successfully and show tooltip when it exceeds from 2 then charts renders successfully but tooltip only getting displayed for intial two lines.
**How can i show tooltip for all the lines when it exceeds from 2.**
below the code snippet of plotOptions and series data.

```
  plotOptions: {
                area: {
                    fillOpacity:0.0001,
                    lineWidth: 2,
                    marker: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    shadow: false,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            lineWidth: 2
                        }                   
                    },                     
                    tooltip: {
                        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><br><table style="height:auto;width:300px;white-space:normal !important;overflow:auto">',
                        pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:black;font-weight:normal;padding:2px;text-align: justify">{series.name}: </td>' +
                            '<td style="color:black;font-weight:normal;padding:0">{point.y}</td></tr>',
                        footerFormat: '</table>',
                        shared: true,
                        useHTML: true
                    },
                    threshold: null
                }
            }
```

below is `series:` data

```
[{"name":"Text1","type":"area","data":[[1262304000000,367],[1293840000000,0.1],[1325376000000,387],[1356998400000,397],[1388534400000,407]]},
{"name":"Text2","type":"area","data":[[1262304000000,272],[1293840000000,1.1],[1325376000000,292],[1356998400000,302],[1388534400000,312]]},
{"name":"Text3","type":"area","data":[[1262304000000,916],[1293840000000,2.1],[1325376000000,936],[1356998400000,946],[1388534400000,956]]},
{"name":"Text4","type":"area","data":[[1262304000000,546],[1293840000000,3.1],[1325376000000,566],[1356998400000,576],[1388534400000,586]]},
{"name":"Text5","type":"area","data":[[1262304000000,726],[1293840000000,4.1],[1325376000000,746],[1356998400000,756],[1388534400000,766]]},
{"name":"Text6","type":"area","data":[[1262304000000,774],[1293840000000,0.2],[1325376000000,794],[1356998400000,804],[1388534400000,814]]}]
```

**update:**
I further investigated and found it shows tooltip for all when we start mouse hover from either start or end point of line in the chart but it doesn't show tooltip if start hovering line anywhere apart from starte or end  point

Comment: There is nothing in your posted code preventing it from showing. Do you have demo site (like jsFiddle) where you can duplicate this issue?

Comment: Thanks for reply..i further investigated and found it shows tooltip for all when we start mouse hover from either start or end point of line in the chart.so it doesn't seemss to be data issue there something realted to point.y it seems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/vr9B8/  ?

```
 tooltip: {
        formatter:function() {

            var len = this.series.chart.series.length - 1;
            if(len > 2)
                return 'content of tooltip';
            else
                return false;       
        }
    },
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.In the fiddle which you created tooltip is shown for initial/top two lines not for all